# laravel не мигрирует

Tags: php, laravel

Начал изучать Laravel. у меня Windows 10.

```html
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = Laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at F:\OpenServer\domains\app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("could not find driver")
      F:\OpenServer\domains\app\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:31

  2   PDOException::("could not find driver")
      F:\OpenServer\domains\app\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:27

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Модуль php нужно установить или включить для работы с БД.

- Для mysql - `php_mysql`
- Для sqlite - `php_sqlite`
- Для postgresql -
  `php_pgsql`

Зависит от того, что используете как локальный сервер на Windows.